# what is the correct syntax function pointer list with class member?

Tags: pointer-to-member

I have a list of function pointers, the non-class member compiles without errors, but the class member compiles with errors:

error: cannot convert 'void (CVdmConfig::*)()' to 'fp {aka void (*)()}' in initialization

CVdmConfig::writeConfig is a void function.

```
typedef void (*fp)();
fp  fpList[] = {&valvesCalib,&CVdmConfig::writeConfig} ;
```

What do I wrong ?
best regards
Werner

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the rest of your code, there is not much I can debug, but here is an example that works:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void valvesCalib() {
    cout << "inside function\n";
}

class CVdmConfig {
    public:
        static void writeConfig() {
            cout << "inside method\n";
        }
};

typedef void (*fp)();
fp fpList[] = {
    &valvesCalib,
    &CVdmConfig::writeConfig
};

int main()
{
    for (auto f: fpList) {
        f();
    }

    return 0;
}

/*
Output:
    inside function
    inside method


    Program finished with exit code 0
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the missing static definition in the member function. But this leads into other problems with variables in the class. So I use a wrapper for this.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).